# Solaris pkgadd ignores dependencies

Tags: package, solaris, packaging

I have a Solaris package with depend file. When I install the package, it ignores the dependencies.

My depend file looks like this:

> P  SUNWcsu Core Solaris, (Usr)
>   P  XXCore My core package

I am able to install the package even if XXCore is not installed.
My Prototype looks like this:

> i pkginfo
>   i depend
>   i request

Thanks in advance.

BTW, other install files (request, checkinstall, etc) are handled correctly.

---

UPDATE:
I have made some changes to the depend file so it looks like one that works fine. I only changed Tab to white space. Now it behaves differently - I get the following:

> ### Verifying package dependencies.
>
> WARNING:
>       The XXCore package "My core package" is a
>       prerequisite package and should be installed.
>   Do you want to continue with the installation?

It is better, but I want the installation to stop, without the option to continue

Comment: Your depend and prototype files look correct. You need to provide more clues.

Comment: Which kind of information do you need?

Comment: Anything that demonstrate the issue is really happening. The OS you run, the commands you run to make sure the XXCore package isn't already installed, the command you use to install the new package, evidence the depend file is really in the new package and contains the prerequisite.

Comment: OK. OS is SunOS 5.9 64bit. I use "pkginfo | grep XXCore" to verify it is not exists. I did pkgtrans to a directory and verified that the pkgmap contains depend, and the depend file under install is OK. Also, please see update of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Should you want to enforce a prerequisite, you can prevent the package installation by using a [checkinstall or preinstall](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1672/ch3enhancepkg-10289.html) script that check for required the package presence and exit in error if not.